# How can you return multiple COUNTs with varying WHERE definitions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I apologize if the title doesn't quite get across what I want to achieve.  Its been quite some time since I've programmed anything so to warm up I'm jumping into some of my older code to refresh myself and hopefully improve efficiency.

What I'd like to know is if it is possible to count the number of entries in a database field four different times, each time with a field in the WHERE clause changing value - but all with one query.  That may not even be asked properly, so I'll explain what I'm trying to do.

I'm doing some basic login tracking for a script.  I'd like to know four time ranges at which users were logged in: up to 24 hours ago, up to 7 days ago, up to a month ago and over the lifetime of the script.

Currently I'm doing something along the lines of this:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM USERTABLE WHERE Time>=LOGINTIME);
```

I run that query four different times with a different value for 'Time' in the WHERE clause.  I've been playing with the COUNT() function, but I can't seem to figure out a way to issue a single query (instead of four) that will fit all of my needs.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the WHEN clause can help you with this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: if i understand well, you can add othere where conditions by using "AND" clause...just Like "WHERE Time>=LOGINTIME AND (TIME>foo and <FOO2) "...

Comment: Ensure you have an index on the `Time` column.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I do have the index on it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
 ID,
 COUNT(*) login_count0,
 SUM(CASE WHEN LOGINTIME >= Time1 THEN 1 END) login_count1,
 SUM(CASE WHEN LOGINTIME >= Time2 THEN 1 END) login_count2,
 SUM(CASE WHEN LOGINTIME >= Time3 THEN 1 END) login_count3
FROM USERTABLE
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Would this combined query be more efficient than 4 separate queries?  I'm getting mixed answers from those I've asked.  My main goal here is efficiency to a degree.

Comment: A single scan is almost always more efficient than multiple scans.

Answer (score 1):

Using UNION, as @AlexP suggested, you can select the data as asked for. Below is an example in T-SQL (SQL Server) but UNION is available to all major databases.

```
DECLARE @User TABLE (
    UserId  INT,
    LoginTime   DATETIME
)

INSERT @User VALUES
(1, '2012-01-01 11:00'),
(1, '2012-02-01 11:00'),
(1, '2012-02-02 11:00'),
(1, '2012-02-03 11:00'),
(1, '2012-03-01 11:00'),
(1, '2012-03-02 11:00'),
(1, '2012-03-03 11:00'),
(1, '2012-03-04 11:00'),
(1, '2012-03-05 11:00'),
(1, '2012-08-01 11:00'),
(1, '2012-09-01 11:00'),
(1, '2012-10-01 11:00'),
(1, '2012-11-01 11:00'),
(1, '2012-12-01 11:00'),
(1, '2013-01-01 11:00'),
(1, '2013-02-01 11:00'),
(1, '2013-03-01 11:00'),
(1, '2013-04-01 11:00'),
(1, '2013-05-01 11:00'),
(1, '2013-06-01 11:00'),
(1, '2013-07-01 11:00'),
(1, '2013-08-01 11:00'),
(1, '2013-09-01 11:00'),
(1, '2013-10-01 11:00'),
(1, '2013-11-01 11:00'),
(1, '2013-11-02 11:00'),
(1, '2013-11-03 11:00'),
(1, '2013-11-20 11:00'),
(1, '2013-11-20 11:00'),
(1, '2013-11-21 11:00'),
(1, '2013-11-21 12:00'),
(1, '2013-11-21 13:00')

SELECT 'today', COUNT(*)
FROM @User
WHERE LoginTime >= '2013-11-21'
UNION
SELECT 'last 7 days', COUNT(*)
FROM @User
WHERE LoginTime >= '2013-11-14'
UNION
SELECT 'last month', COUNT(*)
FROM @User
WHERE LoginTime >= '2013-10-21'
UNION
SELECT 'ever', COUNT(*)
FROM @User
```